# How to prevent connection from being reset/forcibly closed in SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to run a long query in SQL Developer but the query can never finish. I always get

> IO Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

or some other error along those lines. This always happens after exactly 15:00 min.

How can I figure out what is causing the connection to be closed? And, how can I make sure the connection stays open until the query finishes?

SQL Developer version: 18.3.0.277

Comment: It would be good to know why the connection is closing first. How long does this query take to run on the server? 10 minutes sounds like a timeout is getting triggered somewhere.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - That is what I'm trying to figure out. All i've figured out in regards to the error is the error message in the post. I don't have access to the server (or know how to tell how long it is executing on the server). Any help towards figuring out the issue and a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually it times out at exactly 15:00 min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a timeout issue, probably set on the server.  It could be set on the client slide.  I would look at your settings on your SQL Developer and see if that corresponds with the client connection duration that you are seeing.  If it is the same amount of time, then make it longer and try again.  I'm thinking more than likely, it is on the database server side and will need to be changed with Database owner privileges.

Of course, because I don't know what the configuration of your set up is, it could be the windows/Unix server itself that is closing the connection.  It could also be a timeout setting in the network.

Lastly, there could be an application setting (that is, the application that is connected to the database could have a timeout setting) that could be forcing the connection to close.

Good luck and let us know if one of these worked.

Please go through these options and see which

Comment: Where would I find this setting on SQL Developer? If it is a network issue is there a way to keep the session alive while the query is executing?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not in expert in SQL Developer, but I did find this article- http://mikecolbertonline.com/blog/fix-oracle-sql-developer-timeout-when-connected-to-azure/    As far as the network, there may be ways to modify the query or the connection to make the network think it's a live connection, but that's assuming that that it still won't timeout after 15 minutes even with activity.  If the latter is the case, you will need to change something on the network side.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the database server so I can't try the solution in the link. I will keep trying to narrow done the cause of the timeout. Thanks

Comment: You could also try running the query in another application like Toad or PL/SQL developer, too. Just a test to see if the issue is with SQL developer.

Comment: @CSCoder the answer may lay there with a DBA or network administrator

Comment: I did notice a timeout occur in other connection types as well with the same query. Sounds like it may be a network timeout. I broke the query into shorter queries and was able to get it to execute. Thanks for the help.